# how to play videos one by one sequentually?

Tags: android, video

how to play videos one by one simultaneously?

Now i have a problem, I have more than 3 videos,Now i have to play first videos, can't move next videos. How to do that...

```
vidview.setVideoPath(vidname[i].toString()+".3gp||.mp4");
System.out.println("\n\n\n File name is: "+vidname[i].toString());
vidview.requestFocus();
vidview.start();
vidview.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mp.stop();
        run(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: define "one by one simulatneously", that sounds antonymic to me.

Comment: `onCompletion` , you should `setVideopath` of new vid and `start()`?

Comment: `onCompletion` is called when video stream reaches the end I think

Comment: "can't move next videos" => what does it mean ?

Comment: @fiddler, Play first videos, can't play second videos. Finally exit in my app..

Comment: May I assume that you want to **play several videos one after the other in the same container**, like a playlist ?

Comment: @IGP String str=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+getPackageName();    
    File fil=new File(str);
    File[] vidname=fil.listFiles();     
    if(vidname!=null){
    for(i=0;i<vidname.length-1;){
      vidview.setVideoPath(vidname[i].toString()+".3gp||.mp4");
      System.out.println("\n\n\n File name is: "+vidname[i].toString());
            vidview.requestFocus();
            vidview.start();            
            vidview.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

Comment: @IGP  public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             mp.stop();
             run(); 
       }
      });

Comment: @KarthikeyanKarthik Don't add code into comment section, please update your question with full code.

Comment: @KarthikeyanKarthik First update your question with code so i can help you more.

Comment: move one by one video... use loop